# How to mirror value in a column in a new column based on ID

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

The dataset I have has NHL player data that looks something like this(simplified):

```
 teamNAME   playerID        gameID     metric       Won/Lost
  CAP       8473345           20          10           1
  WILD      8475467           20          10           0     
  NY        8471345           21          10           1
  STARS     8475756           21          10           0
```

What I want to do is have the opponents teamNAME in all the rows so that it looks like this:

```
 teamNAME   playerID        gameID     metric       Won/Lost    Opponent
  CAP       8473345           20          10           1         WILD
  WILD      8475467           20          10           0          CAP    
  NY        8471345           21          10           1        STARS
  STARS     8475756           21          10           0           NY
```

How do you solve this?

Comment: you have not provided any info on how you link teamNAME with Opponent. How do you know who the opponent is? if it is just next row then create shifted column.

Comment: Oh sorry, I was thinking by gameID and Won/Lost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could [`GroupBy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)  `gameID` and use `transform` with a `lambda` function that rotates the values:

```
df['Opponent'] = df.groupby('gameID').teamNAME.transform(lambda x: x[::-1])

   teamNAME  playerID  gameID  metric  Won/Lost Opponent
0      CAP   8473345      20      10         1     WILD
1     WILD   8475467      20      10         0      CAP
2       NY   8471345      21      10         1    STARS
3    STARS   8475756      21      10         0       NY
```

Comment: Excellent solution, thank you very much, will accept this one!

Comment: @MisterButter Don't forget to accept this answer if it solved your problem. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, had a timer that said I had to wait 8 minutes

Answer (score 1):

Approaching this problem from an SQL angle, you can perform a cross join on gameID and then filter on teamNAME:

```
(df.merge(df[['teamNAME', 'gameID']], on='gameID', how='left')
   .query('teamNAME_x != teamNAME_y')
   .rename({'teamNAME_x': 'teamNAME', 'teamNAME_y': 'Opponent'}, axis=1))

  teamNAME  playerID  gameID  metric  Won/Lost Opponent
1      CAP   8473345      20      10         1     WILD
2     WILD   8475467      20      10         0      CAP
5       NY   8471345      21      10         1    STARS
6    STARS   8475756      21      10         0       NY
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution!

Answer (score 1):

Combining [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
from itertools import chain

grouper = df.groupby('gameID')['teamNAME']
df['Opponent'] = list(chain.from_iterable(x.values[::-1] for _, x in grouper))

print(df)

  teamNAME  playerID  gameID  metric  Won/Lost Opponent
0      CAP   8473345      20      10         1     WILD
1     WILD   8475467      20      10         0      CAP
2       NY   8471345      21      10         1    STARS
3    STARS   8475756      21      10         0       NY
```